# How can I multiply a character N times using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I just want to echo spaces until it fills the size of the terminal.
I can just write spaces between the quotation marks but it takes time and also it looks bad.

I tried simple things like

```
a=" "*100 or a=(" "*100) & echo $a
```

but it won't work.
Is there any way like Space(100) or a better way than typing spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, using `Perl`:

```
perl -sE 'say " " x $col' -- -col=$COLUMNS
```

Or the most simple:

```
printf '%*s' $COLUMNS " "
```

The variable `$COLUMNS` is the number of columns in your shell.